# Multiple artifacts resolved error with ivy-maven-plugin

Tags: maven, ivy

I'm trying to use the [ivy-maven-plugin](http://evgeny-goldin.com/wiki/Ivy-maven-plugin) in order to execute SBT launcher from another Scala program that builds with Maven. (Side note: I'm not looking for answers like: use SBT...)

My ivyconf.xml looks like this:

```
<ivysettings>
   <property name='ivy.checksums' value=''/>
   <resolvers>
      <url name='typesafe-repo'   alwaysCheckExactRevision='yes' checkmodified='true'>
         <ivy      pattern='http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/[organization]/[module]/[revision]/ivys/ivy.xml'/>
         <artifact pattern='http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/[organization]/[module]/[revision]/jars/[artifact](.[ext])'/>
      </url>
      <ibiblio name="maven2-repo" m2compatible="true"/>
   </resolvers>
   <modules>
      <module organisation='com.jcraft' matcher='regexp' resolver='maven2-repo'/>
      <module organisation='jline' matcher='regexp' resolver='maven2-repo'/>
      <module organisation='org.apache.ivy' matcher='regexp' resolver='maven2-repo'/>
      <module organisation='org.scalacheck' matcher='regexp' resolver='maven2-repo'/>
      <module organisation='org.scala-lang' matcher='regexp' resolver='maven2-repo'/>
      <module organisation='org.scala-sbt' name='test-interface' matcher='regexp' resolver='maven2-repo'/>
      <module organisation='org.scala-sbt' matcher='regexp' resolver='typesafe-repo'/>
      <module organisation='org.scala-tools.sbinary' matcher='regexp' resolver='typesafe-repo'/>
      <module organisation='org.scala-tools.testing' matcher='regexp' resolver='maven2-repo'/>
      <module organisation='org.sonatype.oss' matcher='regexp' resolver='maven2-repo'/>
      <module organisation='org.specs2' matcher='regexp' resolver='maven2-repo'/>
   </modules>
</ivysettings>
```

And the Maven plugin definition like this:

```
     <plugin>
        <groupId>com.github.goldin</groupId>
        <artifactId>ivy-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.5</version>
        <executions>
           <execution>
              <id>add-idea-artifacts-compile-scope</id>
              <goals>
                 <goal>ivy</goal>
              </goals>
              <phase>generate-resources</phase>
              <configuration>
                 <ivyconf>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/ivyconf.xml</ivyconf>
                 <scope>compile</scope>
                 <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                       <groupId>ivy.org.scala-sbt</groupId>
                       <artifactId>launcher</artifactId>
                       <version>0.13.0-RC4</version>
                       <!--<classifier>???</classifier>-->
                    </dependency>
                 </dependencies>
              </configuration>
           </execution>
        </executions>
     </plugin>
```

When I execute the build, I get:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.goldin:ivy-maven-plugin:0.2.5:ivy 
(add-idea-artifacts-compile-scope) on project escalante-play: 
Execution add-idea-artifacts-compile-scope of goal com.github.goldin:ivy-maven-plugin:0.2.5:ivy failed: 
Multiple artifacts resolved for [org.scala-sbt:launcher:0.13.0-RC4:jar] - 
[ivy.org.scala-sbt:launcher:jar:launcher:0.13.0-RC4:compile, 
ivy.org.scala-sbt:launcher-interface:jar:launcher-interface:0.13.0-RC4:compile, 
ivy.org.apache.ivy:ivy:jar:ivy:2.3.0-rc1:compile, 
ivy.org.scala-sbt:io:jar:io:0.13.0-RC4:compile, 
ivy.org.scala-sbt:control:jar:control:0.13.0-RC4:compile, 
ivy.org.scalacheck:scalacheck_2.10:jar:scalacheck_2.10:1.10.0:compile, 
ivy.org.scala-tools.testing:test-interface:jar:test-interface:0.5:compile, 
ivy.org.scala-lang:scala-actors:jar:scala-actors:2.10.1:compile, 
ivy.org.specs2:specs2_2.10:jar:specs2_2.10:1.12.3:compile, 
ivy.org.specs2:specs2-scalaz-core_2.10.0-RC3:jar:specs2-scalaz-core_2.10.0-RC3:6.0.1:compile, 
ivy.org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:jar:scala-reflect:2.10.2:compile, 
ivy.org.scala-sbt:interface:jar:interface:0.13.0-RC4:compile], 
specify <classifier> so that only one artifact is resolved. -> [Help 1]
```

I assume I need to use a `classified` but I've no idea really what this classifier really should contain. I tried `launcher` but did not work, any other ideas?

Cheers,
Galder